# Android : Sqlite more than 20 tables performance

Tags: android

I have a question about performance of the application when we are using sqlite database in our app ,  Do will reduce the speed when we use more than 20 tables in our database?
Each tables have 20 rows data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OF course not , You can use more than 20 tables that will not low your speed, I have created an app having around 120000 tuples including all tables.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't. That's only 400 rows of data.